# Vertically centering text in latex tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, text

I am currently working on my master's thesis and I am trying to input a table in my latex document. The following picture will describe what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Centering text in a cell]

I am trying to vertically center the text in cells 1 through 7 in the first line (Gruppe - max. GK-Größe) but do not seem to find a solution for this.

here is the example of the table I am using:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Gruppe~}                                      & \multirow{2}{*}{Nr.~} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}UHPFRC\\Sorte~ \end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fasergehalt\\${[}Vol.-\%]$~ \end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Faser $l/d$\\${[}mm]$ \end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Konsistenz} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}max.\\GK-Größe\\${[}mm]$~ \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Prüfumfang}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ 
\cline{8-12}
                                                              &                       &                                                                          &                                                                                     &                                                                             &                             &                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Balken\\$150$x$50$x$550$\\${[}mm]$\\(hor. Herstellung)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Balken\\$150$x$50$x$550$\\${[}mm]$\\(vert. Herstellung)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Platten\\$450$x$450$x$50$\\${[}mm]$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Würfel\\$100$x$100$x$100$\\${[}mm]$\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Zylinder\\$100$x$200$\\${[}mm]$\end{tabular}  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{1}                                            & 1                     & FN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 2                     & FM                                                                       & 2                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 3                     & FH                                                                       & 3                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{2}                                            & 4                     & FN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 13/0,16                                                                     & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 5                     & FM                                                                       & 2                                                                                   & 13/0,16                                                                     & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 6                     & FH                                                                       & 3                                                                                   & 13/0,16                                                                     & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{3}                                            & 7                     & FN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 20/0,3                                                                      & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 8                     & FH                                                                       & 3                                                                                   & 20/0,3                                                                      & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4\\ \end{tabular}} & 9                     & GM                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & SCC                         & 8                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 10                    & GN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 13/0,16                                                                     & SCC                         & 8                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{5}                                            & 11                    & FN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & F52                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 12                    & FN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & F52                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{6}                                            & 13                    & FN                                                                       & 1                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 &                                                                                               & \checkmark                                                                                           &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 14                    & FH                                                                       & 3                                                                                   & 12,5/0,192                                                                  & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 &                                                                                               & \checkmark                                                                                           &                                                                     & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7\\ \end{tabular}} & 15                    & G-                                                                       & 0                                                                                   &                                                                             & SCC                         & 8                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
                                                              & 16                    & F-                                                                       & 0                                                                                   &                                                                             & SCC                         & 1                                                                                 & \checkmark                                                                                             &                                                                                             & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                   & \checkmark                                                                  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Versuchsprogramm}
\label{tab:Versuchsprogramm}
\end{table}
```

Please note, that I am using the \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} for German language.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you very much!
Nicco

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In order to vertically center the column headers of the first 7 columns, you could use `\multirow{5}{*}{Gruppe} ` instead of `\multirow{2}{*}{Gruppe~}` and the like.

Comment: Apart from that, I also suggest using `siunitx` for the units as well as dropping the `resizebox` as this will only lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout you document. There are better ways to make your table fit into the textwidth, though which one to use specifially depends on the available space (documentclass, font size, margin sizes,...)

Comment: Thank you very much, leandriis! I adjusted the number, as you suggested and now the text is centered.

Thank you for the following two suggestions, I am about to adjust all units with the siunitx package.

Thank you for your help again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

With the command `\multirow` of `multirow`, you have to provide the number of physical lines. With the command `\Block` (provided by `nicematrix`) you provide the number of logaical rows of the tabular and the content is mathematically centered.

You can use `\Block` to merge cells both vertically and horizontally and then use the key `hvlines` to draw all the rules, excepted in the blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Versuchsprogramm}
\label{tab:Versuchsprogramm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{12}{c}}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{Gruppe} 
  & \Block{2-1}{Nr.} 
    & \Block{2-1}{UHPFRC\\Sorte} 
      & \Block{2-1}{Fasergehalt\\{} [Vol.-\%]}
        & \Block{2-1}{Faser\\ $l/d$\\{} [\si{\mm}]}
          & \Block{2-1}{Konsistenz}
            & \Block{2-1}{max.\\ GK-Größe\\{} [\si{\mm}]}
  & \Block{1-5}{Prüfumfang}  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &   
            & \Block{}{Balken\\ (hor.)} 
              & \Block{}{Balken\\ (vert.)} 
                & Platten
                  & Würfel
                    & Zylinder  \\ 
\Block{3-1}{1} & 1  & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 2  & FM & 2 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC &   & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 3  & FH & 3 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\Block{3-1}{2} & 4  & FN & 1 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 5  & FM & 2 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 6  & FH & 3 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\Block{2-1}{3} & 7  & FN & 1 & 20/0,3     & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 8  & FH & 3 & 20/0,3     & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\Block{2-1}{4} & 9  & GM & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 10 & GN & 1 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\Block{2-1}{5} & 11 & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & F52 & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 12 & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & F52 & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\Block{2-1}{6} & 13 & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 &            & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 14 & FH & 3 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 &            & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\Block{2-1}{7} & 15 & G- & 0 &            & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark       & \checkmark       & \checkmark      \\
                   & 16 & F- & 0 &            & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark       & \checkmark       & \checkmark      \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion. In addition to adapting the second argument of `\multirow` according to the actual number of lins of text, rather than to the number of table rows, I also made some further adjustments. First of all, I used `siunitx` for the units, removed `resizebox` and rotated teh table to a landscape orientation. In order to make sure the table first into the textwidth, I shortened the column headers and placed the removed information below the table. I also added the `cellspace`  package to add a small amount of vertical shite space around the cells. As an aternatiev, I also included a second, different table layout based on `booktabs`:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Versuchsprogramm}
\label{tab:Versuchsprogramm}
\begin{tabular}{|*{12}{0c|}} 
\hline
\multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Gruppe}} 
  & \multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Nr.}} 
    & \multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{UHPFRC\\Sorte}} 
      & \multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Fasergehalt\\{} [Vol.-\%]}} 
        & \multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Faser\\ $l/d$\\{} [\si{\mm}]}} 
          & \multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{Konsistenz}} 
            & \multirow{3.5}{*}{\thead{max.\\ GK-Größe\\{} [\si{\mm}]}} 
  & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\thead{Prüfumfang}}  \\ 
\cline{8-12}
  &  &  &  &  &  &   
            & \thead{Balken\\ (hor.)} 
              & \thead{Balken\\ (vert.)} 
                & \thead{Platten} 
                  & \thead{Würfel} 
                    & \thead{Zylinder}  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{1} & 1  & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 2  & FM & 2 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC &   & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 3  & FH & 3 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & 4  & FN & 1 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 5  & FM & 2 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 6  & FH & 3 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{3} & 7  & FN & 1 & 20/0,3     & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 8  & FH & 3 & 20/0,3     & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{4} & 9  & GM & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 10 & GN & 1 & 13/0,16    & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{5} & 11 & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & F52 & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 12 & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & F52 & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{6} & 13 & FN & 1 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 &            & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
                   & 14 & FH & 3 & 12,5/0,192 & SCC & 1 &            & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{7} & 15 & G- & 0 &            & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark       & \checkmark       & \checkmark      \\
                   & 16 & F- & 0 &            & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark       & \checkmark       & \checkmark      \\
\hline
\multicolumn{12}{l}{}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Balken (hor.) = \SI{150x50x550}{\mm}, horizontale Herstellung}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Balken (vert.) = \SI{150x50x550}{\mm}, vertikale Herstellung}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Platten = \SI{450x450x50}{\mm}}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Würfel = \SI{100x100x100}{\mm}}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Zylinder = \SI{100x200}{\mm}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Versuchsprogramm}
\label{tab:Versuchsprogramm}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}l@{~/~}l *{7}{c}} 
\toprule
\thead{Gruppe}
  & \thead{Nr.}
    & \multirow[t]{3}{*}{\thead[t]{UHPFRC\\Sorte}}
      & \multirow[t]{3}{*}{\thead[t]{Fasergehalt\\{} [Vol.-\%]}} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow[t]{3}{*}{\thead[t]{Faser\\ $l/d$\\{} [\si{\mm}]}}} 
          & \multirow[t]{3}{*}{\thead[t]{Konsistenz}} 
            & \multirow[t]{3}{*}{\thead[t]{max.\\ GK-Größe\\{} [\si{\mm}]}} 
  & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead{Prüfumfang}}  \\ 
\cmidrule{9-13}
  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   &  &  &   
            & \thead{Balken\\ (hor.)} 
              & \thead{Balken\\ (vert.)} 
                & \thead{Platten} 
                  & \thead{Würfel} 
                    & \thead{Zylinder}  \\ 
\midrule
1 & 1  & FN & 1 & 12,5 & 0,192         & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 2  & FM & 2 & 12,5 & 0,192         & SCC &   & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 3  & FH & 3 & 12,5 & 0,192         & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\addlinespace
2 & 4  & FN & 1 & 13   & 0,16          & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 5  & FM & 2 & 13   & 0,16          & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 6  & FH & 3 & 13   & 0,16          & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\addlinespace
3 & 7  & FN & 1 & 20   & 0,3           & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 8  & FH & 3 & 20   & 0,3           & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\addlinespace
4 & 9  & GM & 1 & 12,5 & 0,192         & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 10 & GN & 1 & 13   & 0,16          & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\addlinespace
5 & 11 & FN & 1 & 12,5 & 0,192         & F52 & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 12 & FN & 1 & 12,5 & 0,192         & F52 & 1 & \checkmark &            &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\addlinespace
6 & 13 & FN & 1 & 12,5 & 0,192         & SCC & 1 &            & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
  & 14 & FH & 3 & 12,5 & 0,192         & SCC & 1 &            & \checkmark &            & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ 
\addlinespace
8 & 15 & G- & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & SCC & 8 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark       & \checkmark       & \checkmark      \\
  & 16 & F- & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & SCC & 1 & \checkmark &            & \checkmark       & \checkmark       & \checkmark      \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Balken (hor.) = \SI{150x50x550}{\mm}, horizontale Herstellung}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Balken (vert.) = \SI{150x50x550}{\mm}, vertikale Herstellung}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Platten = \SI{450x450x50}{\mm}}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Würfel = \SI{100x100x100}{\mm}}\\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small Zylinder = \SI{100x200}{\mm}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, leandriis! You shed light in the darkest of days!
Thank you for the time you spent editing the table and for the two excellent variants of it. I appreciate what you did and I will adopt the first variant into my work.

Thank you and stay healthy!